# A problem in classifying a point as increasing or decreasing.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

In order to calculate the rate of change, we always need 2 points. Even in the case of instantaneous rate of change, this is true, although the interval is infinitesimally small.

***Suppose now, the derivative at a point is 0. Doesn't this mean there are two points (again, the interval being infinitesimally small) such that the function values are the same?***

***If the above statement is true, then, therefore, it will not be possible to declare any point whose derivative is 0 as being a part of a function on an increasing interval or decreasing interval.***

Please correct me if my reasoning is faulty.

Comment: Sounds like you figured out Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: If $0 = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ it signifies that the numerator approaches $0$ *faster* than the denominator does.  See for example $f(x) = x^3$, where $f'(x) = 0$ at $(x=0)$ despite the fact that there is no value of $x \neq 0$ such that $f(x) = f(0).$  Here $f(x) = x^3$ is a strictly increasing function.

Comment: I recommend starting to think in terms of limits and not in terms of "infinitesimally small", which is difficult to make mathematically precise. As an example, the rate of change of $y=x^3$ at $x=0$ is equal to $0$, even though $x^3$ is a strictly increasing function. Without limits (that is, thinking only of really-small intervals), we're not going to be able to make our peace with situations like that.